# Scala "Try" return type and exception handling

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch, return-type

I am a newbie for **Scala** and now am trying to complete an exercise. How can I return an **InvalidCartException** while the function return type is **Try[Price]**

```
//Success: return the calculated price
//Failure: InvalidCartException

def calculateCartPrice(cart:Cart): Try[Price] = {
    if(isCartValid(cart)) {
        //Calculations happen here
        return Try(Price(totalPrice));
    }
}

def isCartValid(cart: Cart): Boolean = {
    //THIS WORKS FINE
}
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *"how to make the `Try` contain an exception"*, then use the `Failure()` like below:

```scala
def calculateCartPrice(cart:Cart): Try[Price] = {
    if(isCartValid(cart)) {
        //Calculations happen here
        Success(Price(totalPrice));
    } else {
        Failure(new InvalidCartException())
    }
}
```

Then, given a `Try` you can use `getOrElse` to get the value of success or throw the exception.

Answer (score -1):

`Try` will catch the exception for you, so put the code that can throw the exception in there. For example

```
def divideOneBy(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try { 1 / x}

divideOneBy(0) // Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

If what you have is a `Try` and you want to throw the exception when you have a `Failure`, then you can use pattern matching to do that:

```
val result = divideByOne(0)

result match {
    case Failure(exception) => throw exception
    case Success(_) => // What happens here?
}
```

[The Neophyte's Guide to Scala](https://danielwestheide.com/books/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala/) has lots of useful information for people new to Scala (I found it invaluable when I was learning).

Comment: Hi, I see the point however, the question is about throwing InvalidCartExcepotion Failure. How can I do this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If that doesn't help, please clarify.